# How to run For loop in twig file in php opencart to make the results should be like below

Tags: php, opencart

Suppose,

$a=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

```
then 

in the for loop, it should run 1,2,3,4

and then 5 then 6,7,8,9 and then 10

then exit the loop.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [batch](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/batch.html) and [slice](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/slice.html) Twig filters for this. If you batch the results by groups of 5, then slice the first 4 and the 5th element you are able to loop through the results in the way you want.

Example code:

```
{% set items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] %}
{% for batch in items|batch(5) %}
    <p>item 1 through 4</p>
    {% for item in batch|slice(0, 4) %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}
    <p>5th item</p>
    {% for item in batch|slice(4, 1) %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```